# How to flow text from a box to another with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have several boxes in html as

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

defined with css

```
.box{
width : 200px;
height : 300px;
display :  block;
float : left
}
```

Is there a way to provide a log text in the parent `DIV` and flow the text within child `DIV`s with `CSS`? or it should be done with `Javascript`?

Of course, it does not matter where to provide the text, I just want to flow the excess text to the next box.

Comment: CSS is a style sheet language and not a functional language. You need JavaScript for that.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `columns` property?  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Comment: @cimmanon yes I am looking for something like `columns` in `CSS3`, but wish to apply it to box (not only column with unlimited height).

Comment: @All - All you have to do is set a height on the element that you're adding the columns to, and it will wrap accordingly.

Comment: @SvenBieder the times are a-changing. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/diving-into-css-regions--net-25061

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your HTML to be a single element containing the content, such as:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

And then add these style specifications:

```
.box {
   -moz-column-count: 3;
   -webkit-column-count: 3;
   column-count: 3;
   height: 10em; /* Or whatever height is appropriate. */
}
```

For more information on CSS Columns, see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts#The_columns_shorthand.